# How to add custom behaviour to symfony cache:clear?

Tags: php, caching, symfony1, symfony-1.4, apc

I need to add a simple call to `(new sfAPCCache())->clean()`, or to `apc_clear_cache()` when the command `./symfony cc` is performed.

Anyone knows how to achieve this? In which point should I edit my symfony application, or how should i register this additional behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I discovered that I can listen to an event to add new behavior to `./symfony cc`:

```
$this->dispatcher->connect('task.cache.clear', array('ClearAPCCache','clearCache'))
```

Remains the problem that is not possibile to clear the APC cache from a command-line task because APC cache is related to the web server process, while the symfony command is a command-line script.

Comment: If you configure your web server to be accessible locally, you can have the command line call an APC cache clear URL with curl or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to create your own custom task.

```
./symfony generate:task your_task_name
```

In this task (in the `lib` folder) you just have to run something like

```
protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
{
    // Run your own apc cache
    // ...

    /// Then run the cache:clear
    $this->runTask('cache:clear');
}
```

Comment: In our system the command `symfony cache:clear` is called on a large number of applications in a centralized manner, so it is important that I can overwrite the behavior of the cache:clear. Adding new tasks would not solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @francescostablum but you won't have many others options, as I said.

Comment: Actually, I discovered that I can listen to an event: `$this->dispatcher->connect('task.cache.clear', array('ClearAPCCache','clearCache'));` -- remains the problem that is not possibile to clear the APC cache from a command-line task.

Comment: because APC cache is related to the web server process, while the symfony command is a command-line script. This is what I understood from my experiments. Not sure it's 100% correct